# Express JS form validation with hapi/Joi doesn't validate form data correctly

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I have a form which i'm trying to validate using the hapi/Joi package, but it doesn't take values from the form. Instead it returns the first validation error because all schema keys take the value of "undefined". How can I solve this problem? Also is there a way to print out errors to the user without refreshing the page in Express? If yes please let me know about it.

My Express code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

app.set('view engine','ejs');

const urlEncodedParser = app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('main');
});

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    surname: Joi.string().min(5).required(),
    age: Joi.number().integer(),
    email: Joi.string().email({minDomainSegments: 2}).required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    confirm: Joi.any().valid(Joi.ref('password'))
});

app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    req.body.id = uuidv4();
    console.log(req.body);
    const result = Joi.validate({

        name: req.body.name,
        surname: req.body.surname,
        age: req.body.age,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirm: req.body.confirm

    }, schema,(error,value)=>{
        if(error){

            printError(error);

        }
        else{
            console.log('success');
        }
    });

});

function printError(error){
    console.log(error);
}

app.listen(3000);
```

My form:

```
<form action="/register" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="text" name='name' class="form-control" value="">
        <input type="text" name='surname' class="form-control" value="">
        <input type="number" name='age' class="form-control" value="">
        <input type="email" name='email' class="form-control" value="">
        <input type="password" name='password' class="form-control">
        <input type="password" name='confirm' class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" value="OKAY">

    </form>
```

The error which I get:

```
{ ValidationError: child "name" fails because ["name" is required]
    at Object.exports.process (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\@hapi\joi\lib\errors.js:202:19)
    at internals.Object._validateWithOptions (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\@hapi\joi\lib\types\any\index.js:763:31)
    at module.exports.internals.Any.root.validate (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\@hapi\joi\lib\index.js:145:23)
    at app.post (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\index.js:31:24)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
  isJoi: true,
  name: 'ValidationError',
  details:
   [ { message: '"name" is required',
       path: [Array],
       type: 'any.required',
       context: [Object] } ],
  _object:
   { name: undefined,
     surname: undefined,
     age: undefined,
     email: undefined,
     password: undefined,
     confirm: undefined },
  annotate: [Function] }
```

It says "name is required" even when i'm filling in the name input in my form and hitting enter.

Comment: I can't see what your console.log(req.body) is returning, also body-parser is no longer required, express 4+ comes with inbuilt body-parser.

Comment: Iv'e just checked and it doesn't seem to be returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
const urlEncodedParser = app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

to

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: For files you'll require either multer or busboy, body-parser or express parser can't handle `multipart/formdata`. Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme